# Can we edit Page Metadata in Tridion using SiteEdit 2009?

Tags: tridion, siteedit

In SDL Tridion 2009 SP1 we have Components that are added to Structure Group and Page Metadata which are then output on the Page as a Component Presentation. We have done this to allow users to set global content per site section without the need to add it to every single Page in the Structure Group.

When we output the Component with a Component Template with manual tags we get a red box around the Presentation and the tooltip of the SiteEdit box says “Removed”. When using the exact same Component Template in the Component Presentations tab and rendering that on the page the content is editable.

Is it possible using SiteEdit 2009 to inline edit a component added as Page/Structure Group metadata?

Note: We are aware of an outstanding bug in SDL Tridion 2009 SP1 that when you go to open a component added to Page/Structure Group metadata that it always opens it read-only. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: If you want to edit Page Metadata why do you mention "we had added some component"? What's the relation?

Comment: Hi @user1341643 - Thanks for posting your first SDL Tridion Q on SO - I see you also have an Area 51 account - You might consider committing to the SDL Tridion Proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 - Thanks for your support

Comment: So what you want to do is to edit components that are NOT in the page, they're linked to from Metadata - Not possible unless you know Tridion really well. Editable content must be added to the page, not to its metadata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do this but you have to make sure that your markup is correct. I have done this before by marking the SiteEdit Component Presentation as QueryBased which seems to make SiteEdit ignore it's usual rules where the Component must be added in the Component Presentation list

```
<!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: { 
"ID" : "CP1", 
"ComponentID" : tcm:32-204298", 
"ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:32-204519-32", 
"Version" : "16", 
"IsQueryBased" : true} 
-->
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to either:

- Expose the metadata of the page in a "visible" area of your page with the correct SE markup
- Open the page in CME and edit the Metadata there.

Tridion UI 2012 added a button with "Edit Metadata" functionality, but that's not available for SE 2009

Answer (score 2):

Not through inline editing. You can of course open the Page editing popup and edit the metadata there.

Of course if you want to edit fields of the Component that you've linked in Page Metadata, you can just render out that Component Presentation into the HTML and mark it with the correct SiteEdit commands as Nuno suggests.